# Retrofit2 downloading data async and getting a progress bar

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I need to show a progress bar while downloanding something from my webservice, because i need to make a fragment transition just when the download was complete. I've tried to many different things, but im still stucked on the start. I got the transition before the download finish

Someone can show me an example or show me a direction from where to look to solve this problem?

```
 public void efetuarLogin() {
    loadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    final iRequestsTramita requestsTramita = TramitaService.getInstance().usarServico();
    Call<RespostaTramita> callCapturarUG = requestsTramita.getResposta(new LoginTramita(userLogin,userPass));
    callCapturarUG.enqueue(new Callback<RespostaTramita>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RespostaTramita> call, Response<RespostaTramita> response) {
            //loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                doing something...
                baixarObrasGestor();
                loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                doing something...
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RespostaTramita> call, Throwable t) {
           ...
        }
    });
}

public void baixarObrasGestor(){
    List<Gestao> listaIdRequisicao = bancoDadosController.gerarListaRequisicaoGeoPB(userLogin);
    iRequestsGeoPB requestsGeoPB = GeoPBService.getInstance().usarServico();
    //make some requests to webservice
    for (Gestao gestao : listaIdRequisicao){
        ...
        Call<List<RespostaGeoPB>> callBaixarObras = requestsGeoPB.baixarObrasGestor(headers, paramRequisicao);
        callBaixarObras.enqueue(new Callback<List<RespostaGeoPB>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RespostaGeoPB>> call, Response<List<RespostaGeoPB>> response) {
                ...doing something
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RespostaGeoPB>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TESTE", "erro: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    selecionaUG(); //do  the fragment transition
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further about what you've tried so far? And if you supply a code snippet, make sure it's as small as possible to allow others to reproduce the problem - avoid including anything that isn't related to the question at hand.

Comment: I'm trying make a interface right to call on callback to show the progress of my download. When i get 100% i will call the function to do the transition

Other trys:
-put the transition function outside of the last for
-wait before the transition
-sleep before the transition

Comment: I guess you are not getting code 400 but something else..

Comment: I'm getting the correct data, but the transition is occurring before the download finishes. Not matter where i put the transition on code, i will try your example @Avezan. I just didnt understand from where is coming this loadingComplete();

Comment: `loadingComplete()` is just to make you understand whatever you want to put in your wrap up code. like `loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I override `Callback<T>` this provides you option to include all custom events you want to raise like.

`public abstract class RetryCallback<T> implements Callback<T> { ... }`

If you only want to hear when loading completes this much skleton is enough. But make sure some exception is not raised out of your `onResponse` or `onFailure`. I have often seen transition without notice when some exception is raised. Pack your code inside `try-catch` and see if it is not the problem case.

```
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    if(!response.isSuccessful()){
        // ....
        loadingComplete();
        return;
    }
    // ...
    loadingComplete();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    // ...
    loadingComplete();
}
```